# How can I use NLP to extract the main food word from an ingredient?

Tags: nlp

Let's say I have the following list of ingredients:

```
1 fresh baguette, cut into sandwich parts
1 tablespoon good quality unsalted butter, per sandwich (so 4 tbsp if making 4 sandwiches)
1 apple or gala preferably (2 apples for 4 sandwiches)
1 slice of english blue cheese, preferably a stilton (again, or 4 slices for 4 sandwiches)
```

What I want to do is extract the main food word from the list of ingredients. So the result should be:

```
baguette
butter
apple
cheese
```

How can I use NLP to do this? Or is there something else I can use to do this?

Comment: How do you define "main food word"? Is it always the first ingredient in the line?

Comment: @OliverMason Well the "main food word" is basically the actual food in the ingredient. The other words in that ingredients list is just talking about quantity and measurements, which I don't need to know. Just want to know the actual ingredient itself.